# Wrong return value when multiplying

Tags: javascript, oop, multiplication

The output of `console.log()` is the value of `width` when I use the `getRatioValue()` function to multiply the inserted value of `height` and the calculated ratio. I cannot find why this is happening.

```
var soFunction = function(args) {
   this.width = args.width || 0;
   this.height = args.height || 0;

   this.getRatioValue = function(value) {
      var ratio = this.width / this.height;
      return value * ratio;
   };

   console.log(this.getRatioValue(this.height)); // returns 1200
}

// Initialize object
var test = new soFunction({width: 1200, height: 980});
```

Comment: what you want as output? here you are multiplying and diving height so it is showing width value to you.

Comment: You're dividing the width by the height... then multiplying it by the height again, so you end up with what you started with, ie the width.  It may help if you can explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Your code is working fine i am getting width `1200` only in console..check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g6msszn5/

Comment: I see now what I am doing wrong. I needed to divide the height by width and not in reverse. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an simple mathematic operation. If you will write your function on one line you will get.

`value` is equal to `height`, so

```
return this.height * this.width / this.height
```

`this.height`'s destroy each other and it returns the `this.width`